# Making sure an NSString's numeric value will fit into a long long

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, validation

I was wondering how it is possible to validate input from a `UITextField` in a  case such as this:

```
NSString *str = [UItextfield1 text];
long long value = [str longLongValue];
```

How do I check first if the number won't wrap around, and if it is numeric before passing it on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't check first, check after. [The docs for `longLongValue`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW2) say that if the string can't be converted,  `value` will be 0. If its magnitude would be too great, you'll get `LLONG_MAX` or `LLONG_MIN`

Comment: will the value of the long be set to that ("LLONG_MAX") ?

Comment: It will be `LLONG_MAX` if the numeric value is too high (positive), or `LLONG_MIN` if it is too low (negative).